# Test that thread culture was set in async controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nunit, cultureinfo

I'm trying to migrate an asp.net mvc 5 controller to use async/await. I have a problem with testing that the correct culture has been set.

In the old (non-async) version of the code, the unit test passes because everything is running on the same thread. In the new (async) version of the code, the unit test fails because the current culture is not maintained after calling an async/await method.

In the new version of the code, the culture is set correctly, and the view has the correct culture set. The only problem is that I can't test this in my NUnit test, because it's outside of an await call.

Do you know how I can fix this? I have provided a pseudocode-like version of the code I use below.

**Old code:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // Look up user in database
    var dbUser = database.GetUser(User.Identity.GetUserId());

    // Set preferred culture
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(dbUser.PreferredCulture);
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(dbUser.PreferredCulture);

    // Do some other work
    DoSynchronousWork();

    return View();
}

[TestFixture]
public class TestClass
{
    [Test]
    public void TestIndex_CorrectCulture()
    {
        // Mock database
        database.GetUser().Returns(new User(){PreferredCulture = "de"});

        // Call controller
        _controller.Index();

        // Check that the thread culture was correctly set - this passes
        Assert.AreEqual("de", Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture);
        Assert.AreEqual("de", Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture);
    }
}
```

**New code:**

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    // Look up user in database
    var dbUser = database.GetUser(User.Identity.GetUserId());

    // Set preferred culture
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(dbUser.PreferredCulture);
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(dbUser.PreferredCulture);

    // Do some other work
    await DoAsynchronousWork();

    return View();
}

[TestFixture]
public class TestClass
{
    [Test]
    public async Task TestIndex_CorrectCulture()
    {
        // Mock database
        database.GetUser().Returns(new User(){PreferredCulture = "de"});

        // Call controller
        await _controller.Index();

        // Check that the thread culture was correctly set - this fails because the culture inside _controller.Index() is lost after the await call
        Assert.AreEqual("de", Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture);
        Assert.AreEqual("de", Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture);
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems to me the easiest way to test this is to include something culture-dependent in the view. That way your test is testing that the correct view is returned (behavior), not that the thread's culture was set (implementation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using mock library, try moving code not testable to a service:

```
interface IThreadCultureSetter
{
    void SetCurrentThreadCulture(CultureInfo ci, [CallerMemberName]string callerMethod = null);
}

class ThreadCultureSetter : IThreadCultureSetter
{
    public void SetCurrentThreadCulture(CultureInfo ci, [CallerMemberName]string callerMethod = null)
    {
        // Set thread culture
    }
}
```

Change your controller action to use the interface:

```
private readonly IThreadCultureSetter _cultureSetter;

public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    // Look up user in database
    var dbUser = database.GetUser(User.Identity.GetUserId());

    // Set preferred culture
    _cultureSetter.SetCurrentThreadCulture(new CultureInfo(dbUser.PreferredCulture));

    // Do some other work
    await DoAsynchronousWork();

    return View();
}
```

In your test, provide a mocked `IThreadCultureSetter` and verify that the method was called with desired `CultureInfo`:

```
// Assume you use Moq
Mock<IThreadCultureSetter> cultureSetterMock;

// The SetCurrentThreadCulture must be called by Index method
mock.Verify(x => x.SetCurrentThreadCulture(It.Is<CultureInfo>(ci => ci.Name == "de"), "Index"));
```

The fact is that `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` is async static (value stored in AsyncLocal) and is not test friendly, because its value only exists for current captured async scope.

**UPDATE**

I just figured out it might be possible to use a custom `SynchronizationContext` to test the thread culture was set (can't guarantee by what) as expected culture:

```
class ThreadCultureInspectionSynchronizationContext : SynchronizationContext
{
    private readonly string _expectedCultureName;

    public ThreadCultureInspectionSynchronizationContext(string expectedCultureName)
    {
        _expectedCultureName = expectedCultureName;
    }

    public bool WasSetToExpected { get; private set; }

    public override void Post(SendOrPostCallback d, object state)
    {
        // When context is switching, e.g. continuation of an await being executed, this method is called.
        // This method could inspect on thread culture, and set flag to true once expected culture detected.
        // This method can only prove that the thread culture was set, but cannot suggest by which method.

        if (!WasSetToExpected)
        {
            WasSetToExpected = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name.Dump() == _expectedCultureName;
        }

        base.Post(d, state);
    }
}
```

In your test, before calling `Index`:

```
var ctx = new ThreadCultureInspectionSynchronizationContext("de");
SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(ctx);
await Index();
...
Assert.IsTrue(ctx.WasSetToExpected);
```

If your thread culture was set by `Index` method, you would expect to see all inspection on thread culture by the synchronization context is your expected one.

Comment: Of course, this would be the obvious answer, but this method does not verify that the culture has been set on the thread that returns the view. If in the future, somebody moves the call to `_cultureSetter.SetCurrentThreadCulture(...)`  into an async method, then this test will pass. But the culture will only be set inside that async method, and not on the thread that actually returns the view.

Comment: That's good point. However, there should be unit test for `ICultureSetter` and its implementation to verify that once the method was changed to async, it sets the culture for parent async scope. The unit test for `ICultureSetter` and the unit test for controller action in total would guarantee that "the action sets culture and the culture sets correctly".

Comment: That test would verify that `ICultureSetter` works correctly, but it wouldn't verify that the controller action is calling it correctly. For that, we should find a way of testing that the action is calling ICultureSetter directly, and not from inside another async scope.

Comment: Well. It is technically possible to check that the `ICultureSetter` must be called by the action method by adding `[CallerMemberName] string callerMethod = null` parameter to `SetCurrentThreadCulture`, which will tell compiler to inject the caller method's name. Though, I feel we might have gone into a rabbit hole :) Might have over tested the method.

Comment: Yep, I think you are right. This solution might not be perfect, but I think it's the best that can be done. I'm going to leave this question open for some time, and if nothing better shows up I'm going to mark this as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: No worries. I also updated another possible solution with custom `SynchronizationContext`. You might want to take a look. :)